# Screen Magnifier in Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: xubuntu, screen, accessibility

I installed Xubuntu for reasons of stability and fluidity in my notebook.

I used to have Ubuntu with Gnome Shell, which used much screen magnifier (I have vision problems). After that bad experience, due to the slowness of the system, but decided to reinstall Ubuntu with Unity, I spoke to also had a screen magnifier, the problem is that the system is quite slow and unstable because it froze and restarted at any moment the computer is not a good practice.

Met Xubuntu, but apparently this little thought in people with some degree of visual impairment.

I tried KMag -> not qualify.

Virtual Magnifying Glass 3.5 -> That qualifies half as wide the screen as usual, but locks the keyboard and mouse actions.

I was told to install GNOME Orca, this is just a screen reader, does not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind raising a bug about the performance issues you found in using gnome shell's magnifier? you can do that here under the component 'magnifier' https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gnome-shell thanks.